# TFS Build 2015 not publishing test results

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

**UPDATE** (I have restructured this question with a new and basic solution and build as the same problem exists there)

I'm using the new build system in Tfs 2015 and I'm using Update 1. I have noticed that on the build summary screen, no test results or Code Coverage results are submitted:

[image]

I have a test step which runs and contains results and I have a .trx and a .coverage file but the test step log contains the warning:

```
##[warning]Failed to publish test results: The value for the Build.Id property is not within the permissible values for it.
```

The Build is very basic, it contains 2 steps and Code Coverage is Enabled on the test step:

[image]

Here is the build def as retrieved by the TEST REST API:

```
    {  
   "build":[  
      {  
         "enabled":true,
         "continueOnError":false,
         "alwaysRun":false,
         "displayName":"Build solution $/IsdDev/SQTestBuild/Main/TestBuildSystem.sln",
         "task":{  
            "id":"71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda",
            "versionSpec":"*"
         },
         "inputs":{  
            "solution":"$/IsdDev/SQTestBuild/Main/TestBuildSystem.sln",
            "msbuildArgs":"",
            "platform":"$(BuildPlatform)",
            "configuration":"$(BuildConfiguration)",
            "clean":"false",
            "restoreNugetPackages":"true",
            "vsVersion":"14.0",
            "msbuildArchitecture":"x86",
            "logProjectEvents":"true"
         }
      },
      {  
         "enabled":true,
         "continueOnError":false,
         "alwaysRun":false,
         "displayName":"Test Assemblies **\\$(BuildConfiguration)\\*test*.dll;-:**\\obj\\**",
         "task":{  
            "id":"ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9",
            "versionSpec":"*"
         },
         "inputs":{  
            "testAssembly":"**\\$(BuildConfiguration)\\*test*.dll;-:**\\obj\\**",
            "testFiltercriteria":"",
            "platform":"$(BuildPlatform)",
            "configuration":"$(BuildConfiguration)",
            "runSettingsFile":"",
            "overrideTestrunParameters":"",
            "codeCoverageEnabled":"true",
            "vsTestVersion":"14.0",
            "pathtoCustomTestAdapters":"",
            "otherConsoleOptions":""
         }
      }
   ],
   "options":[  
      {  
         "enabled":false,
         "definition":{  
            "id":"7c555368-ca64-4199-add6-9ebaf0b0137d"
         },
         "inputs":{  
            "multipliers":"[]",
            "parallel":"false",
            "continueOnError":"true"
         }
      }
   ],
   "variables":{  
      "BuildConfiguration":{  
         "value":"debug",
         "allowOverride":true
      },
      "BuildPlatform":{  
         "value":"any cpu",
         "allowOverride":true
      }
   },
   "retentionRules":[  
      {  
         "branches":[  
            "+refs/heads/*"
         ],
         "artifacts":[  
            "build.SourceLabel"
         ],
         "daysToKeep":10,
         "deleteBuildRecord":true,
         "deleteTestResults":true
      }
   ],
   "_links":{  
      "self":{  
         "href":"http://removed/343974ee-60a8-40ee-a103-37fa5db37c41/_apis/build/Definitions/71"
      },
      "web":{  
         "href":"http://removed/_permalink/_build/index?collectionId=808a695f-85b6-49db-a2df-ca4aaf8bbb9f&projectId=343974ee-60a8-40ee-a103-37fa5db37c41&definitionId=71"
      }
   },
   "buildNumberFormat":"$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)",
   "createdDate":"2015-11-19T07:43:27.977Z",
   "jobAuthorizationScope":"projectCollection",
   "jobTimeoutInMinutes":60,
   "repository":{  
      "properties":{  
         "labelSources":"0",
         "labelSourcesFormat":"$(build.buildNumber)",
         "tfvcMapping":"{\"mappings\":[{\"serverPath\":\"$/IsdDev\",\"mappingType\":\"map\",\"localPath\":\"\\\\\"},{\"serverPath\":\"$/IsdDev/Drops\",\"mappingType\":\"cloak\",\"localPath\":\"\"}]}"
      },
      "id":"$/",
      "type":"TfsVersionControl",
      "name":"IsdDev",
      "url":"http://removed/",
      "defaultBranch":"$/IsdDev",
      "rootFolder":"$/IsdDev",
      "clean":"undefined",
      "checkoutSubmodules":false
   },
   "quality":"definition",
   "authoredBy":{  
      "id":"7d24caba-6c09-4b78-8ff1-2404e0b0ec64",
      "displayName":"Rod Hall",
      "uniqueName":"ISD-NR\\Rod.Hall",
      "url":"http://removed/_apis/Identities/7d24caba-6c09-4b78-8ff1-2404e0b0ec64",
      "imageUrl":"http://removed/_api/_common/identityImage?id=7d24caba-6c09-4b78-8ff1-2404e0b0ec64"
   },
   "queue":{  
      "pool":{  
         "id":2,
         "name":"Back Office Pool"
      },
      "id":2,
      "name":"Back Office Pool"
   },
   "uri":"vstfs:///Build/Definition/71",
   "type":"build",
   "revision":1,
   "id":71,
   "name":"SQ Test",
   "url":"http://removed/343974ee-60a8-40ee-a103-37fa5db37c41/_apis/build/Definitions/71",
   "project":{  
      "id":"343974ee-60a8-40ee-a103-37fa5db37c41",
      "name":"IsdDev",
      "url":"http://removed/_apis/projects/343974ee-60a8-40ee-a103-37fa5db37c41",
      "state":"wellFormed",
      "revision":7
   }
}
```

What is the Build.Id that the warning refers to, how can I view it and set it?

This could even be a problem with TFS 2015 Update 1...

**UPDATE** I'm not sure if it matters but when I go to the Build section of the TFS Admin Console it appears to not be configured:

[image]

I have my application tier on 1 server and then I have 3 Agent Pools each with 3 Agents. There are 3 build servers each of which have 1 agent from each pool installed for a total of 9 agents. I set these up using PowerShell and I downloaded the agent from the TFS page. My builds still work Ok, it's just this tests publishing

Comment: Could you share your detailed configuration of build vNext definition?

Comment: @Rodders, please check my comment under my reply post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Jesse Houwing for helping me on this one. I had to detach and reattach the Team Project Collection using the TFS Admin Console on the App Server. It seems there is an issue with Update 1 (or perhaps one of the Release Candidates).

For those with the same problem, it will obviously take TFS offline but it took less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Check the attached vNext build configuration, with which I can get the Test result and Code coverage. Make sure you have specified the **solution** in `Visual Studio Build` and select **Code Coverage Enabled** in `Visual Studio Test`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have added some more info. Solution is set (parametized) along with Code Coverage Enabled. I will try to create a new basic build of a basic Console app and see what happens. Cheers

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you would use the TFS REST API to check your new build def and let me know what format it expects for id under repositories. Mine is "$/" and I think this is the problem. e.g. http://server:port/tfs/Collection/TeamProject/_apis/build/definitions/70

Comment: Did you create a new build vNext definition to test the new application? Including specifying the solution and enable Code Coverage, is there anything else you have set?

Comment: I did create a new vNext def. and I did specify the solution path and enabled code analysis. The only other thing that I did was removed the publish artefacts and publish symbols steps.

Comment: Removing  the publish artefacts and publish symbols steps won't effect test result publish. I also try with the Tfs2015.Update1.RC2 build, test result still can be published. Please try to create a new team project to see whether you have the same issue.

Comment: Just tried with a new Team Project using a basic solution and build def but no good. Did it work for you on Update 1 RC 1? I might try to upgrade to RC2. Thanks for your help

Comment: I didn't try on Update 1 RC 1 as I didn't have this environment. You can try to upgrade to RC 2, which I have tested without issue.

Comment: I've updated to Update 1 release build and I still have the same issue. All of my build agents have been updated too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue yesterday: Visual Studio Test using Test Agent step was failing with the "The value for the Build.Id property is not within the permissible values for it" error message when it was trying to execute Coded UI tests on the remote test machine. Detaching project collection and re-attaching it back fixed the issue.