# Any Way to Publish Test Coverage Result back to TFS Server?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

In order to distribute the tests into different machine (remote way), we have to use the .testsettings file. In such file, we already configure to enable to collect the test coverage data by:

```
<DataCollectors>
    <DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/CodeCoverage/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CodeCoverage.CoveragePlugIn, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Plugins.CodeCoverage, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="Code Coverage (Visual Studio 2010)">
      <Configuration>
        <CodeCoverage keyFile="xxx.snk" xmlns="">
          <Regular>
            <CodeCoverageItem binaryFile="xxx.dll" pdbFile="xxx.pdb" instrumentInPlace="true" />
```

But the problem is the test coverage data never published back to the TFS server. When diagnostics the build process, the test result already can be published according to the build log:

```
Results file:  d:\Builds\xxxx.trx 
Test Settings: xxx
Waiting to publish...
Publishing results of test run xxx.trx to https://tfs.xxx/tfs/xxx...
Publish completed successfully.
```

It seems the coverage data isn't inside the xxx.trx file, and the build is not smart enough to allocate them and publish them. so from the build summary we can see:

```
23 modules instrumented - 0% of all code blocks covered
```

Is there any way to manually publish such data or write back the test coverage result back to the TFS server via some TFS API or coded activity?

[UPDATE] When check the test result file, it seems the result itself already contain the knowledge about how to find the .coverage file:

```
<ResultSummary outcome="Completed">
    <ResultFile path="VM-TEST01\data.coverage" />
    <ResultFile path="VM-TEST02\data.coverage" />
```

But the problem is the MSTest never publish them onto the TFS server!

Comment: Assuming you are using the new build system, the VS Test step should do this automatically. However if not, Code Coverage results are stored in the .coverage file. You will need to enable Code Coverage on the build step. My question here may help (please answer it too if you can!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752784/tfs-build-2015-not-publishing-test-results

Comment: We do not use the latest build system provided by TFS 2015. The main reason is we want to benefit from the feature of original one that can distribute our tests into different machine or environments by using A test controller with multiple test agents.

Comment: Did you try vstest.console.exe MyTest.dll /logger:TfsPublisher;Collection=http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection;TeamProject=MyProject;BuildName=DailyBuild_20121129.1;RunTitle="Project tests with code coverage data" /EnableCodeCoverage ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to
1). open the build definition, go to **Process** -> **3.Test** -> **Automated Test** -> set the **Type of run settings** option to be **UserSpecified**.
2). Select the .testsettings file in the build definition.

[image]

Then, after  a new build is queued, the code coverage data displayed on the Build Summary page:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. The problem is: we define to use a test settings as an option, and inside the setting file we enable the coverage. If we use the "Enable Code Coverage" as an option, we cannot use any test settings file.

Comment: @Max, if that is the case, you need to set "Type of run settings" to be "UserSpecified". Updated my reply above.

Comment: Thanks Vicky. Could you please share how to configure to enable the coverage in the setting file, is it the same with ours?

Comment: @Max, 1). I have the same .testsettings file defined as yours. 2). When you click the 'Test Result', can you find the 'data.coverage' as attachment? 3). TFS2015 Update1 is installed, would you mind upgrading your TFS2015 to Update1?

Comment: When click "Test Result", the data.coverage can be found as attachment. The TFS test controller and agent are 2013, while the TFS server is 2015.

Comment: And the TFS version we use is Version 14.0.23128.0